# Java spring application.propterties value not getting used by application

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator

I'we just added a new value to my

> application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = *
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime = 27000
```

But when I list out everything when my application is running with this command

> curl localhost:9091/actuator/configprops | jq

I don't get the new value, but instead the default value for **maxLifetime**

```
"dataSource": {
  "prefix": "spring.datasource.hikari",
  "properties": {
    "initializationFailTimeout": 1,
    "validationTimeout": 5000,
    "hikariPoolMXBean": {},
    "readOnly": false,
    "registerMbeans": false,
    "healthCheckProperties": {},
    "isolateInternalQueries": false,
    "leakDetectionThreshold": 0,
    "maxLifetime": 1800000,
```

I thought this was the only thing needed to get the new **maxLifetime** value populated and used by the application.

Answer (score 1):

Your properties file says spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime

Your JSON structure says datasource.properties.maxLifetime